# CustomView(UITableView) after hiding have to access the UITextFields under Customview area

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.5

I am getting `UITableView` when `UITextField` starts editing am hiding this after my functionality get finished.

I have taken static `UITableView`. My problem is after hiding the `UITableView`(CustomView) I am not able to access below `UITextFields` (that are present in UITableView area)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
        if(textField==CompanyName)
        {
            autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
                NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
                substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
                [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
                return YES;
                if([CompanyName.text length]==0)
                {
                    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;

                }
        }


        if([arr4 count]!=0)
        {
            self.autocompleteUrls = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
            viewForautoCompleteTableView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 195, 230)];

            if(autocompleteTableView)
                [autocompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];

            autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,195,150) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
            autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
            autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
            autocompleteTableView.rowHeight=28;

            autocompleteTableView.backgroundView = nil;
            autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            autocompleteTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            [autocompleteTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            [viewForautoCompleteTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,110 ,195,autocompleteTableView.frame.size.height)];


            [viewForautoCompleteTableView addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
            [self.view addSubview:viewForautoCompleteTableView];

            [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
            for(int i=0;i<[arr4 count];i++)
            {
                NSString *curString = [[arr4 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];
                [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];

            }
        }
    [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(currentHtmlElement==@"5")
    {
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CompanyName.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: paste code...once hidden textFields are not visible to user so you must be tryng to access some values written earlier save them before hand

Comment: add your UITextField in uiView not in UITableView

Comment: I will not be able to resolve your question if you have not posted any code.Your question is hardly understand by me.

Comment: @prathyusha would you please upload your project to github,or send it to my mail.I will return you after correcting it.Its very hard to understand what u r doing.

Comment: @Hercules can you tell me mail Id

Comment: yes now I got your mail.Sorry there was a net issue

Comment: its Ok.can you pls find out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add textField delegate as follows:
may it will help you ..

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnuserLocation];
    autocompleteTableView.hidden=true;
}
```

and for button change control Event of UIbutton from UIControlEventTouchDown to UIControlEventTouchUpInside as given below:

```
[btnuserLocation addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showLocation:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It will hide your table view whenever focus is removed from your textField.And let you click on the button behind tableView.

Comment: thnx for ur help .but it is working for some pages only.

Comment: i had one dout posted to your gmail.can u pls check your mail

Comment: you mean picker arrow not working

Comment: no,picker arrow is working picker did select row is not working

Comment: I have check here all is working but slowly

Comment: ok thanQ u helped me alot